# Worker process taking high CPU%

Tags: iis, asp.net, application, pool

All of my websites are hosted in IIS and configured with one application pool. This application pool consists 10 websites running.

It is working fine till today, but all of sudden I am observing that there is sudden up and down % in CPU usage. I am unable to trace out the problem.

Is there anyway to check which website is taking much load among all in the application pool?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Put every website in a separate application pool. Also best pratices - an erro in one site, the way you have set it up, will take down and restart the application pool, i.e. all sites.